# How to get Application Version and display on screen using package_info Package in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to Display application version on Dashboard Screen in Drawer in List tile So how i can do this?

I have a Function for Application Version as below in app_util.dart file.

```
class AppUtils {
  static Future getAppDetails() async {
    final packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    String version = packageInfo.version;
    return version;
  }
}
```

Now i have to get these data on dashboard.dart page in drawer.

How i can Access the getAppDetails() function data to dashboard?

Comment: can you share your dashboard.dart ?. I assume you have not used statemanagement so you can simply store it in a global variable on a getter of app utils and call getAppDetails on start of the app or in the init state .

Answer (score 0):

In dashboard.dart file,you need to call something like `

- String version =await AppUtils.getAppDetails();

so you will wait your value and show.
Next way,you may have some static String version in your utils.dart,
and int your future you can init that property

- class AppUtils { String version?;   static Future getAppDetails()
  async {
  final packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
  version = packageInfo.version;

  } }

in your main file call and wait to this feature

- await AppUtils.getAppDetails();

after in your dashboard.dart just take that value AppUtils.version!